OpenAPI- Referencing a path from external file
I'm trying to document my expressJS API with swagger-ui-express and the yaml package to parse yaml files.
This is the relevant part of my file structure:
└── doc
   ├── test.yaml
   └── openapi.yaml

In the root open api file (openapi.yaml) I try to reference a path from another file.
This is my root openapi.yaml file:
openapi: 3.0.0
info: 
  ...
servers:
  ...
paths:
  /test:
    $ref: "./test.yaml#/test"

And this is my test.yaml fle:
/test:
  post:
    summary: A test endpoint.
    responses:
      "200": 
        description: A test endpoint. 

However swagger ui shows me this error:
Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer: /test does not exist in document

I also tried: $ref: "./test.yaml#/~1test" but I get basically the same error.
If I try with:

$ref: "./test.yaml"
$ref: "./test.yaml#"

I don't get any error but neither the info for my /test enpoint.
If I include the /test path data inside openapi.yaml then it works just fine but I want to modularize my api documentation.
How should I reference a path from an external file inside openapi.yaml?

show the entire test.yaml file.. what is the root node?

@JeremyFiel the content of test.yaml is exactly as I showed in my OP, I also tried adding paths: as the root node but it didn''t solve the problem.

This looks like a bug in swagger UI, the $ref: "./test.yaml#/~1test" syntax should work IMO.
Is it a feasible workaround to remove the leading slash from test.yaml , like
test:
  post:
    summary: A test endpoint.
...

then reference it with $ref: "./test.yaml#/test" ? I mean, in the test.yaml the /test key is really just a name you use for referencing, so it shouldn't matter too much.

It seems like it, removing the leading slash didn't worked. I just tried with plain json files, just to rule out the possibility that the yaml parser can be the problem but the issue persist, I'll have to post this issue in their github page.
